# (Ruby on Rails) Changing A View Depending On The Presence of an Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running into problems allowing users to change one of their attributes. I want my homepage to prompt the user to set this attribute if they haven't set it.

I've written this method to check for the presence of this attribute:

```
  def start_date_set?
     current_user.start_date?
  end
```

And in my view I've written:

```
<% if is_admin? %>
  #render admin
<% elsif !start_date_set? %>
  #this is what i want to see
<%else %>
  #render users posts
<% end %> 

<%#=if not logged in %> 
<% else %>
  #signup page is rendered
  #this is what shows up
<% end %>
```

I believe the elsif should be triggered if there is no start_date set, which there shouldn't be when a new account is created. However, it does not trigger and instead displays the very final else condition.

Does anyone know why the view that should be being rendered is not?

*edited to add*

This is the migration which attaches a start_date to a user:

```
class AddStartDateToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :start_date, :datetime
  end
end
```

Comment: Try to drop console http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#console and inspect `start_date_set?` method. Which value does it return?

Comment: If I type "start_date_set?" in the console on the homepage it says "NoMethodError: undefined method `start_date?' for nil:NilClass" - altho I'm not sure if this is how you inspect the method.

Comment: I'm guessing you should actually be doing an authentication check on the controller layer that should redirect the user to the sign in page instead of handling it in the view.

Comment: Voting to close: you simply have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my methods would only work once the account was activated, I'm not sure why but this is how it worked out. Once I tried the above code with an activated account it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your else statement at the bottom with another if statement to check if you are logged in or not. For this you can check the presenece of `current_user` object. With this if statement, your view looks like:

```
<%#= if logged in %> 
<% if current_user %>
  <% if is_admin? %>
    # render admin
  <% elsif !start_date_set? %>
    # this shows up if you are logged in and start_date_set? returns false
  <% else %>
    # render users posts
  <% end %> 
<%#= if not logged in %> 
<% else %>
  # signup page is rendered when not logged in
<% end %>
```